# Android - BarChart, Bargraph

Tags: android, bar-chart

I want to implement a feedback/rating chart in my android app.(it is like when you open the google play and check an app's feedback there is a colourful graph from users who had voted it) Can anyone help me how to start that? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MPAndroidChart, or another Chart library external to the default libraries. It's difficult to implement a bar graph or any sort of graph on Android; you'd have to make a listview, and it would have to be oriented horizontally.

Comment: Thank you @DonLarynx. I am gonna check those libraries.